# Solve $\sin 3x = \cos 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with this problem. I am aware that this problem has been posted before but the answers didn't really satisfy me.

This is how far I've gotten with this:

[image: As you can see I don’t know how to solve for x when sin x = -(1 +/- sqrt(5))/4]

Comment: If $t=sin(x)$ and you have solved for $t$, then $x = \arcsin (t)$ for your $t$ values no?

Comment: Please link to the previous postings of the problem you say you have found, and explain what you find unsatisfying about their answers.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help but, cool last line: $-\frac{\phi}{2}$!

Comment: @IntegrateThis As you can see I don’t know how to solve for x when sin x = -(1 +/- sqrt(5))/4

Comment: @leun As they said, just take the inverse sin of both sides

Comment: @rhkoulen he is expecting some kind of ratio of $2 \pi$ I'm guessing.

Comment: Why not use $\cos \theta = \sin ((4n+1) \pi / 2 - \theta)$ and similar?

Comment: Ya, so try and find $a,b$ with $a+b = \frac{3\pi}{10}$ where $sin(a+b) = t$ and $sin(a)$ and $sin(b)$ have explicit solutions using special triangles/sin identities.

Comment: @Troposphere he has three values for $t$, one being $1$ where $\arcsin(1) = \pi$

Comment: $3x+2x=\frac\pi2$ where $x=…$

Comment: @ACB That should be $\frac\pi2 + 2n\pi$ for an arbitrary integer $n,$ in order to capture all solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach:

We have

\begin{align*}
\sin(3x)=\cos(2x)&\implies\sin(3x)=\sin(2x+\pi/2)\\
&\implies\sin(3x)-\sin(2x+\pi/2)=0\\
&\implies2\cos\left(\frac{3x+2x+\pi/2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3x-2x-\pi/2}{2}\right)=0\\
&\implies2\cos\left(\frac{5x+\pi/2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-\pi/2}{2}\right)=0\\
\end{align*}

So,

\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{5x+\pi/2}{2}\right)=0&&\text{or}&&\sin\left(\frac{x-\pi/2}
{2}\right)=0\\
\frac{5x+\pi/2}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi&&\text{or}&&\frac{x-\pi/2}
{2}=n\pi&&\forall n\in\mathbb Z\\
x=\frac{4n+1}{10}\pi&&\text{or}&&x=\frac{4n+1}2\pi&&\forall n\in\mathbb Z\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, fixed!

Comment: $n$ in the statements $T(x)=n\pi$ and $x=G(n)$ is quantified with $\exists$, not with $\forall$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin{3x}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-3x)=\cos{2x}$
$\frac{\pi}{2}-3x=\pm{2x}+2k\pi$

where $k\in Z$

$x=\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}$

OR

$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+{2k\pi}$